# Mostrar errores en un formulario con una barra de progresos. [Laravel & JS]

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, ajax

Necesito que se muestren los errores típicos al realizar el formulario si algo ha ido mal. Actualmente  tengo una barra de progresos que funciona correctamente por JS pero el problema es que no consigo que se muestren los errores. Si quito el JS de la barra de progresos los errores se me muestran perfectamente. Se que faltaría alguna condición... Podéis echarme una mano? Estoy trabajando con Laravel.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      var bar = $('.bar');
      var percent = $('.percent');
      $('form').ajaxForm({
          beforeSend: function() {
              var percentVal = '0%';
              bar.width(percentVal)
              percent.html(percentVal);
          },
          uploadProgress: function(event, position, total,        percentComplete) {
              var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
              bar.width(percentVal)
              percent.html(percentVal);
          },


          success: function(xhr) {
              alert('File Has Been Uploaded Successfully');
              top.location.href="{{ route('post.index')}}";
          }

      });
  }); 
  });
```

```css
.progress { position:relative; width:100%; background-color: #dfe0df; border-radius: 5px; }
        .bar { background-color: #00ff00; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 5px; }
        .percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; left:50%; color: #040608;}
```

```html
<div class="py-12 max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">    
  @if(count($errors) > 0)
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
          <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>
      @endforeach
  @endif          
      <form action="{{route('post.create'}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf


  <div>
  <x-jet-label for="description">Description:</x-jet-label>                
      <textarea type="textarea" id="description" name="description" maxlength="1500" style="overflow:hidden"
          class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm min-w-full"></textarea>                
  </div>     


  <div class="pt-2"> 
  <x-jet-label for="file">{{ __('Upload file') }}:</x-jet-label>
  <x-jet-input type="file" name="file[]" multiple accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"/>
  </div>




  <div class="pt-2 pb-2">
      <x-jet-button>
          Post
      </x-jet-button> 
  </div>   

  <div class="progress">
      <div class="bar"></div >
      <div class="percent">0%</div >
  </div>


</form> 



</div>
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasadsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdscs scascsacsacsacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
(estas letras las he puesto prk sino no me dejaba postear)

Comment: Estás enviando el formulario a través de AJAX y no veo que tengas definida una condición cuando el envío falla. Así como tenés un `success` debés tener un `error` o algo similar (no se que estás usando). En ese método o definís como mostrar los errores o hacés un redirect como estás haciendo en el `success` para que aparezcan los errores que tenés definidos desde Blade.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @azeós !! Por lo que me comentas es necesario pasarle un error para que funcione. Actualmente tengo esto:
https://pastebin.com/ffU4xEgS
Pero no tengo idea ... Me interesa pasarle la variable {{$error}}

Comment: Si hacés un `error: function(xhr) { console.log(xhr); }` qué te devuelve?